# Double question marks instead of figure reference

Tags: errors

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat.jpg}
\caption{A boat.}
\label{fig:boat}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:boat} shows a boat.

\end{document}
```

I compile this more than once. I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't confirm this. I I compile the code once, I get the described `??`. If I compile the code twice, I get the expected output.

Comment: the posted document produces `Figure 1 shows a boat` after the second run. (I added `[draft]` so we don't need `boat.jpg` to test)

Comment: make sure you are not deleting the `.aux` file between runs.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response! I realize it might be some issue with the PDF previewer in VSCode. No matter how many times I build, it never corrects the problem. But if I open the .pdf outside of VSCode it's fine.

Comment: @JayBundy a pdf viewer can not change a `??` to a `1` there may be issues with showing the included image with different viewers but not with the  cross reference text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I understood the OP correctly, the pdf previewer does not update the shown pdf after the second run.

Comment: @leandriis ah, OK that makes sense.